# Can we know the radio status programmatically in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Please tell me if the following things are possible or not in Windows Phone 7:

1. getting radio started time
2. finding the playing station name
3. getting radio stopped name

Comment: Yes. You can do that. API is exposed to do the same. Is there any specific problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

None of the information you are after is available through the SDK.

For details of the functionality that the FMRadio class supports see MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio_members(v=VS.92).aspx